# Creating a lofi, abstract texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects, illustration, texture

I'd like to incorporate a texture similar to this album cover for a project I'm working on. Any suggestions of good starting points/tutorials to check out? I'm used to using photoshop, illustrator, sketch and photography so anything incorporating those tools is best.
[image: Classixx Faraway Reach]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks pretty simple.

I would just make some lines of color and use the liquify tool or some smudge one. You can try adding a mask to achive defined edges.

Try not to put complementary colors together or you will have a grayish image.

Work on RGB mode.

### Edited

If you want a totally editable aproach take a look at mesh fills: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/meshes.html

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'll give your suggestions a shot.